# Difference between living with peace and living in peace

Tags: prepositions

Do 'living with peace' and 'living in peace' mean the same? I find it used interchangeably by many; however, I think there is a subtle difference in the meaning. Let's take 'living with peace' Here, 'Peace' can be a person's name; it can also be the feeling of peace. If it is a feeling, doesn't it have to end with more words like, 'living with peace in our hearts' or 'living with peace of mind?'

Comment: Do we really use such phrases as 'living with peace' or 'living in peace'?  I haven't heard "peace" being the name of anyone.  The usually heard phrase is 'peace of mind'. However, it should be OK using sentences like, "Don't disturb them; let them live with peace of mind." In piece quickly takes one to the phrase "rest in peace..." God forbid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ***living with peace*** isn't a natural English expression (but [*They lived **in** peace*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22they+lived+in+peace%22) obviously is).

Comment: There are about 2,920,000 results in google if you search "living with peace" and there are many book which go by that title. I don't understand why this isn't a valid question.

Comment: Because English: Prepositions are quirky and hard to justify.

Comment: They would mean different things. To live in peace would be viewed in a positive way. To live "with" peace would have overtones of dissatisfaction, e.g., "The warriors only came alive during battle; for the rest of the time they were forced to live with peace."